# Only apply tag using semantic-release

Tags: semantic-release

As far as I read the documentation of [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release), it does many things in sequence.
It applies the tag in the commit and publish it to the Github releases.

Q: Is it possible to separate those 2 steps somehow?

- In 1st stage, I only want to apply tag
- In 2nd stage, I want to publish the artifact to Github.

Note: We are using the following command

```
npx semantic-release
```

The steps done by semantic-release: [semantic-release: release-steps](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release#release-steps)